# push notifications form javascript using quickblox

Tags: javascript, cordova, chat, ionic-framework, quickblox

I've created a simple 1:1 chat using quickblox but I have problem with push notification. my users are subscribed to quickblox push service and when I send push notification from admin pannel everything work. When I send pushnotification form user to another user there is and error:

> "status":"error","message":"Unprocessable Entity","detail":"{\"errors\":{\"base\":[\"No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for APNS (Apple Push) (through SDK or REST API)\"]

```
var params = {
notification_type: "push", 
environment: "production", 
user: {
   ids: recipientID
},
message: "ew0KICAgICJhcHMiIDogew0KICAgICAgICAiYWxlcnQiIDogIllvdSBnb3QgeW91ciBlbWFpbHMuIiwNCiAgICAgICAgImJhZGdlIiA6IDksDQogICAgICAgICJzb3VuZCIgOiAiYmluZ2JvbmcuYWlmZiINCiAgICB9LA0KICAgICJhY21lMSIgOiAiYmFyIiwNCiAgICAiYWNtZTIiIDogNDINCn0=", 
                push_type: "apns"
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(params))
            QB.messages.events.create(params, function(err, response){
                if (err) {
                    console.log('push err '+JSON.stringify(err));
                }
                else {
                    console.log('push ok '+JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            });
```

I want to send push notifications to the recipientID.
Some one can help me!?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Sending push notifications to Web is impossible.